# How to watch just one time using input in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is a input tag in vue template. I want to use 'text' type not 'password' type.

```
  <input type="text" v-model="form.password" />
```

So I made  a watch code to change text string to ** string.

```
  watch: {
    "form.password": function(val) {
      this.form.password = *
    }
  }
```

But when I type one character it is changed to ' * ' , so 'watch' caches again and again infinitely.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your watch problem by using the input event instead, which only gets fired when you type something.

```
<input type="text" :value="form.password" @input="updatePassword" />
```

Then in your method

```
methods: {
    updatePassword: function(ev) {
        this.form.password = "*";
    }
}
```